# Bootstrap 3 collapse: Get non-collapsed height of a collapsed element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have some bootstrap panels where the `panel-heading` is used to collapse the `panel-body`. I'm wondering if it's possible to access the non-collapsed height of the `panel-body` when it is in the collapsed state?

You can check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kj91ffL/), where the panel body is already collapsed. Clicking the panel header will expand the body. When the body is collapsed, how can I determine its height when it's not collapsed (without expanding it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is specific to Bootstrap 3 so this answer is as well and may not be useful generally.

In bootstrap 3, when an element is collapsed its height is explicitly set to `0px` using element styling. You can disable this in-line element styling and access its height via:

```
$(element_selector)['height']('').height();
```

This will not show the element, because in addition to setting the height to `0px`, when the element is collapsed its `display` property is set to `none`.

Comment: I was thinking about this the all day and I came to this. You can give a class to the rows in the panel and than style them to a fixed height, let's say 50px, we need to add some tolerance because the rows don't reach the bottom of the panel so let's say again 50px. Whit this in place you could have the height of the container. See the updated example. you can change the two values till you have the  needed result. Adding or deleting rows would than give you always the (almost) right height.

Comment: My answer gives the exact height of the element, does not require use of fixed height, and is not dependent on the element containing rows of equal size (or rows at all, for that matter).

Comment: That's good to Know @Joseph. Thanks to point me to this, because honestly I didn't know that. So talking to you has been very usefull for me. I am really sorry that I can not do for you what you were looking for. Maybe next time I will. By the way have a nice holydays.

Answer (score 0):

You can have track of how many element are inside the panel and than from there you could calculate his height:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var rowHeight = 50;
  var marginBottom = 50;
  var nrOfRows = 0;
  $('.my-table .row').each(function(){
     nrOfRows ++
  })
  var panelHeight = (rowHeight*nrOfRows)+prseInt(marginBottom)
})
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I want the height of the element, not the quantity of rows it contains. Height as in CSS height.  Preferrably in pixels, I suppose.

Comment: As I know I don't think this will be easy to do. What I did is the following. The height of your row is probably 40px. So when you know that you have two rows you also know that the height of the container is 70px. I am curious so I am wondering why you want to know the height of the hidden panel.